# map not created in hector_slam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I started to work with hector slam. My system is ubuntu 11.10 and fuerte full.

when i have tried to run the tutorial  [hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData)

Every thing seems ok..but when i have tried to save the map two files have been created: test.pgm and test.yaml,but the image in test.pgm is blank how can i fix this error ?

This what i have done exactly

```
roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
```

then

```
rosbag play Team_Hector_MappingBox_RoboCup_2011_Rescue_Arena.bag  --clock
```

there is shot of rviz & terminal

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54169/map-not-created-in-hector_slam/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
What we can't see in the screenshot: Is there a map that looks OK? Also is blank = empty or blank= all grey?

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-04**:
The normal screen of rviz  and the image that has been saved from map is blank

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
Please add rxgraph or similar output to check if the topics are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you start playing bag file add "param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/" in ur launch file. This will take clock from ur rosbag file.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-04**:
Thanks..u mean to modify the launch file of hector_slam packge ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-04**:
yeah .. and dont forget to make the value "false" if u are not using map file.